# Git submodules — exclude specific files/directories

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I'm attempting to use Gits 'submodules' feature to include 3rd party code in a project. I only need a couple of files from the submodule and wish to exclude all the docs, etc that come with it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

In my submodule I had an `/examples` folder I wanted deleted *locally* to prevent those files being seen by an autogenerated makefile; `origin` had to remain oblivious to the deletion.

In git CLI:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged <path/to/file>`

To track local changes once again:

`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <path/to/file>`

Or in SourceTree, create a custom action as per [Fabian Blechschmidt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795913/equivalent-to-git-update-index-assume-unchanged-in-sourcetree).

**NOTE** This is *not* the same as "Stop tracking", where `origin` will indeed also stop tracking the file on commit - not what you want.

Comment: Did this work on a folder? I can only get it to work on files?

Comment: @MattSephton This was written 4 years ago. I cannot possibly remember for certain.

Comment: no worries. Having re-read your reply it seems you were referring to working on files within a directory.

Answer (score 2):

A git submodule is a git repository embedded inside another git repository.  Other than that there's nothing special about it -- a submodule behaves the same way as any other git repository.  You get all the files and all the history associated with the repository when you clone it.

If you just want a couple of files and you're not interested in tracking the change history of the third-party project, maybe you should just copy the specific files into your project and call it done.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, I want to still track changes and push/pull the submodule as needed (the 3rd party library is my own)

Comment: I appreciate this. I figgered that was the case (I have a similar issue -I develop a library of submodules, and each module has a whole lot of extra code for unit testing. I really only need the .m and .h files. All the rest, I can leave behind).