# Equivalent to "git update-index --assume-unchanged" in SourceTree

Tags: git, version-control

So far I used `git update-index --assume-unchanged` on the database configuration file after I filled in the database password because I don't want my database password to get into the public code repository.

Now I wanted to try and use SourceTree for a while and I can't find a way to do the same with it: The file should remain in the repository but I just want SourceTree to ignore changes to that file in my working copy.

Comment: I'm glad I noticed this question and the [popular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26846857/543738) below for adding a custom action.  I was hoping this "assume-unchanged" feature would work for new files that haven't been added to the repository, but it doesn't.  It gives the error, "fatal: Unable to mark file fu.bar".

Comment: @LS for files not added yet to the repository use the ignore feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite likely that SourceTree doesn't have a feature for manipulating the index in that way (although I could be wrong, but it doesn't seem to). However that doesn't mean you can't drop down to the terminal in order to issue that command, but continue to use SourceTree for everything else.

Comment: Thank you, Vic. Just using git in the terminal to do it like I did before works good for me. I wouldn't have thought that SourceTree respects what I do with git in the terminal, but it does.

Comment: Though the terminal is always an option, adding a Custom Action as @Fabian Blechschmidt answers suggests is the way to go.

Answer (score 48):

I just defined custom action for this task.

Make sure the path to git is correct.

Thanks to @RobCroll from the comments, we now have a Windows version:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe (for x64 use: C:\Program Files\Git\bin)
Parameters: update-index --assume-unchanged $FILE
```

[image]

Comment: Windows version: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe  Parameters:update-index --assume-unchanged $FILE

Comment: It would be nice if SourceTree had a variable, like `$GIT`, that holds the full path of the git it uses.  That could be used in the "Script to run" field.  I've noticed in the command history that SourceTree just uses `git` without a full path.  I've tried that and it works.  This may be a Bad Idea™, but I thought that if this custom action runs in the same environment as SourceTree's other commands, it will probably be safe enough.

Comment: Afaik you could easily find where your git is by running `whereis git`

Comment: I can confirm @RobCroll 's answer works for windows. Mine was in `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe` (x64).