# Android Studio NDK: exclude native files?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I notice that the later versions of gradle have a means to `exclude` resources, however I have not seen any examples supporting this where we specify `.jni.srcDirs`, which unselectively includes *everything* under each `.srcDir` path.

Does anyone know of a way to specify certain subdirectories to exclude, for NDK?

What about excluding individual files by extension?

My only alternative seems to be to explicitly list files that *are* used.

P.S. I don't want to use Android.mk; if possible I would prefer to stick with Gradle's automation.

Comment: are you referring to the [gradle experimental plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) that shipped with the [new C++ support in Android studio](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview)?

Comment: Not really, from what I see there. What I've done for now is to delete unwanted files (example sources) from the source folders and then had git [ignore those deletions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228439/git-submodules-exclude-specific-files-directories/31609537#31609537). This way I can keep the repos the same but still have Android Studio / gradle not process those unwanted files. Hopefully it will soon be possible to specify individual sources for gradle i.e. without manual modification of `Android.mk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for the present, this doesn't seem to be possible through gradle.

What I've done for now is to delete unwanted files (example sources) from the source folders (then had [git ignore those deletions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228439/git-submodules-exclude-specific-files-directories/31609537#31609537) so it doesn't try to check in changes to the project's submodule dependencies). This way I can keep the repos the same but still have Android Studio / gradle not process those unwanted files.

Of course, if you cut gradle out of the picture altogether, you can do whatever you like with your makefile, including solving this problem.